# exclude some schemas from select catalog privilege oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Is it possible to create a user and give access to the metadata of some schemas and exclude some schemas and also just give the access to metadata only.

Answer (score 0):

The select_catalog_role gives access to the metadata only.

Comment: My requirement is to give select_catalog_role of some schemas only.

Comment: Have a look how the select_catalog_role is defined, you can create a new role, similar to it but with the modifications for your purpose

Comment: How to create the role to give the privileges in such a way.